# Upload image default image to s3 with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, amazon-s3, carrierwave

We are using [`carrierwave gem`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) to upload our images on a rails project.
We need to support the creation of the object without an image, but the application will run on several platforms and we don't want to support objects without images in everyone o that platforms, so we want to have a default image.

So this was the first solution

```
class IconUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.id}"
  end

  def default_url
    "/images/icons/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end

  version :thumbnail do
    process resize_to_fill: [200, 200]
  end

  version :high_resolution do
    process resize_to_fill: [400, 400]
  end
end
```

The problem with this is that all the devices will come to the server (not to S3) looking for that default image.
At the same time its a problem with the multiple versions of the image.

So this second solution came:

```
class CategoryController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    @uploader = IconUploader.new(@category, :icon)
    uploader.cache!(File.open("app/assets/images/photos/picture.jpg"))
    @category.image=@uploader
    @object.save
  end

  ...

end
```

This solves the problem of the multiple resolutions and it always goes to S3 to get the image. But the problem here is that it will duplicate the default image on S3 many times.

Our third solution could be a to use an already created image on Amazon as default URL, but it has the same problem with the version so we don't even implement it.

Can any one think of a better solution for this problem?